# divide the screen into four in unity , basketball game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have programmed a basketball game.

My question is that how can I divide the screen into 4 canvas but only one camera and use four different balls with 4 controls differents, for four players. Drag and throw a game in unity with C#.

Comment: I think you need to be more clear in your ask. Are you looking for a server-client connection? Are these players connecting to an 'online' game? Visualization of what you are trying to achieve will also help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want four Cameras? If so, you may need to look at Render Textures. If not, and you just want to mock some bits on 4 canvases, then it is very possible. What platform is this for?

Comment: hi, only one camera , by android maybe someday iphone, yes  4 canvases with 4 controls.thanks

Comment: If on Android / Touch Screen, you can grab different "Touches" using the finger id to sort of follow one input compared to another:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-fingerId.html

If you are on PC you will probably need to bind a load of Keys and use those for the different players. 

For the different Canvases, set up 4 of them at the root, each with an Empty Game Object on it, with anchor points (min x, min y, max x, max y):
0, 0, 0.5, 0.5
0.5, 0, 1, 0.5
0, 0.5, 0.5, 1
0.5, 0.5, 1, 1
(did these in my head so may not be perfect)